# Putting exit; in PHP config file

Tags: php, exit, exploit

I have a script that's named config.php.  Inside this script are variables that contain mysql login info, etc.  Some kid keeps saying he has root access to my site and recently we just heard of a leak though don't know if it can be substantiated or not.  I know that you put exit; after header(location:.. to stop script executing; is the same thing necessary in this case?  How can this be exploited?

Comment: I don't think there is vulnerability within your scripts in this case. If 'some kid' has root access to your server, your PHP scripts is the least of your concerns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has root access to your server, he can just open the file and view the password. Also, he can reset the mysql root password, and gain access to it.

Some resources:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/218138/finding-how-a-hacked-server-was-hacked
- https://serverfault.com/questions/179876/hacked-by-black-jaguar

Answer (score 0):

You should add `exit;` after `header(location:...`, that's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody have root access to your Server, will never tell you about that! Exit will not help you in this case... Variables of your config.php will not be displayed, because the file is parsed by PHP. You better check Server logs, processes, shell history...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should consider putting your configuration file outside of the document root folder.

Secondly, if your `config.php` doesn't produce any output, accessing it with a browser will show an empty page.

Someone who has compromised your system can basically do anything, regardless what's inside your scripts ;-)